# Use of Label attribute in apex:page tag

Tags: visualforce, documentation

I am quite confused about this statement in [Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_page.htm):

> label || 
>   String  || The label that is used to reference the page in Salesforce setup tools.

I tried with following code:

```
<apex:page controller="DummyPOC" label="Superr">

    <script>
        function testMethod(){
            console.log('$Page:  ' + $Page.DummyPOC);
            alert('Test Method called.'); 
        }
    </script>

    <apex:form>
        <apex:commandButton value="click me"  onclick="testMethod();return false;"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

My assumption is, I should get this page in "S" list of pages. However it is not showing there(since it has name, DummyPoc. It will be showing in "D" list).

Could you pls let me know, what that statement means in documentation?

Comment: what do you mean by "S" list of pages and "D" list?

Comment: @SantanuBoral I was referring to list. Setup->Pages->alphabetical lists of pages

Comment: If you create a visualforce page from UI then it will take whatever it is defined as label and name in UI. It will not consider whatever is defined in `apex:page` as attribute

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! But, I guess, this shall not referred as  Attribute then.  It is of no use, since we are giving label while creating a page.